# Index-dependent lock/mutex mechanism for synchronization

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, locking

Let's say I have an array (of fixed size) that is shared between multiple threads/processes.

Is there a (generalized, optimally lightweight) mechanism for a lock/mutex so that I don't have to lock access to the entire array if I just want to read/write from a certain position in the array?

A brute force approach would be to simply have one mutex for each element in the array. However, this seems a bit overweight and I'm looking for alternative solutions.

A short example, to show what I mean:

```
//Setup
int a[50];

void threada()
{
   lock(a,4); //supposed to lock index 4 of array a from access by other threads
   write(a,4); //writes something to index 4
   unlock(a,4); 
}

void threadb()
{
   //now all of this shouldn't block, since i'm accessing index 5, not 4
   lock(a,5); //supposed to lock index 5 of array a from access by other threads
   write(a,5); //writes something to index 5
   unlock(a,5);
}

void threadc()
{
   //all of this, however, should block if threada is already accessing it
   lock(a,4); //supposed to lock index 4 of array a from access by other threads
   write(a,4); //writes something to index 4
   unlock(a,4);
}
```

Comment: Does reading and writing occur in the same threads? If not then you could have the writing threads send update messages. It all really depends on the particulars of the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply have a trade-off between the two methods you mentioned. Have a smaller number of locks each protecting a section of the array i.e. K locks, each protecting N/K items.

Then, depending on the data access patterns in your application you can use a striped (i.e. lock 0 is protecting index 0, K, 2K,... lock 1 index 1, K+1, 2K+1,... etc.) or a contiguous strategy.